# Math calculation with decimal isn't correct

Tags: math, decimal

I have a C# method and which accepts **three `string` parameters**. After converting them to `decimal`, I am trying to perform a simple math calculation. I don't understand, why isn't the result correct?

```
decimal d = MyFunction(x, y, z);


public decimal MyFunction(string x, string y, string z)
{
    decimal dx = 0;
    decimal dy = 0;
    decimal dz = 0;

    Decimal.TryParse(x, out dx);
    Decimal.TryParse(y, out dy);
    Decimal.TryParse(z, out dz);

    decimal result = dx - dz + dy;
    return result;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give more details: what are x,y,z equal to and what are you expecting to get in the result variable?

Comment: Think about what you're asking, and the information you've given us: "Why is `[unknownValue1] - [unknownValue2] + [unknownValue3] = [unknownValue4]` wrong?"

Comment: If you were expecting something other than 151804.25, you were mistaken.

Comment: Tell us what you expect. Maybe we find out what the calculation should look like.

Comment: Why did you delete your input and expected output from the question? The  question is now incomplete and could be downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit in response to more question information:**
I don't see your problem. I get 151804.25, which is the correct result of doing (1186197.29 - 1260711.19) + 226318.15.

Maybe you're confused because you expect x - z + y to mean x - (z + y) and not (x - z) + y?
C# operator precedence for - and + is left to right, so it means (x - z) + y. If you want x - (z + y), you will have to write it that way.

---

Floating point calculations are often fundamentally inexact (although `decimal` does a lot better than `float` and `double` for monetary and similar usage).
Example:

```
decimal x = 1m / 3m;
decimal y = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 1e6; i++)
{
    y += x;
}
```

Result of `y`:

> 333333.33333333333333333072026

Comment: @Joren: Ignoring overflow issues, and assuming equal precision of inputs and outputs, floating decimal point addition/subtraction *are* completely exact.

Comment: "The binary representation of a Decimal value consists of a 1-bit sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the 96-bit integer and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction." In other words, it's not an approximated value like float or double.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: the set of real numbers is infinite, while the set of numbers that can be represented exactly by a Decimal is finite, so a Decimal is still an approximation.

Comment: Edited my answer to show an example of `decimal` being inexact. I wouldn't call this overflow, this is simply a consequence of limited precision. Limited precision is pretty fundamental to this kind of datatype.

Comment: Although it was wrong for me to say they're *never* exact. That's blatantly untrue. Edited that as well.

Comment: @Powerlord: Depending upon context, `Decimal` may hold either an exact or inexact value; unfortunately, there's no indication of which it holds at any given moment.  Addition of exact values is associative within reasonable ranges, but addition of inexact values is generally not unless the intermediate results stay in a range of roughly +/- 8.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>If the result you're getting is zero, then it could be that `TryParse` couldn't parse the strings.</strike>

You should replace the calls to `TryParse` with `decimal dx = Decimal.Parse(x);` and see if it throws an exception.

If that isn't the problem, we cannot help you until you provide more details.

What are `x`, `y`, and `z` equal to, and what is the result you're getting?

**EDIT**: In response to the additional information added to the question, it appears that everyone else is correct and the problem is probably the lack of parenthesis.

Comment: +1. Ignoring the result from the TryParse calls means that there are three potential points of failure. If a string is unparsable, the value will be zero.

Comment: This is not the problem. There is no problem. The answer returned by Florjon's function is correct.

Comment: Nothing against you, SLaks, but why do people keep voting this answer up? The inputs in the question parse fine.

Comment: Because I answered before he added the inputs to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what your problem is.  This function is working correctly, but look closely at this line:

```
decimal result = dx - dz + dy;
```

You may have intended to write this:

```
decimal result = dx + dz + dy;
```

or this:

```
decimal result = dx - (dz + dy);
```

Comment: don't work even in this way. it seems that the value are right, but when i am doing xxxx.29 - xxxx.19 it says that is equal to xxxx.9
this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Florjon: how are you getting that? When I execute this line: "2000.29M - 1000.19M", I get "1000.1".

Comment: If the first number is greater than the second, the answer is correct: 1000.29 - 2000.19 = -999.9.

Comment: @Ralph: I think you meant, "If the *second* number is greater than the *first* ...and they **ARE** in this case: 1260711.19 > 1186197.29.

Comment: @Dan: True, thanks. I did turn that around. My math in this case is clearer then my English. As any mathematician would tell you: just trust the formulas.

Comment: @Ralph: I think you hit the nail right between the eyes. The question asker needs a math class.

Comment: @Ralph: Indeed, in this case it seems the poster's biggest mistake was simply not trusting the computer.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Hit the *nail* right between the *eyes*? That's some nail ;)

Comment: Brilliant. I'm remembering that expression. :)

Comment: I use that expression so much that sometimes I use it even when I *mean* to say "hit the nail right on the head". Oh well, it's half of one, six dozen of the other.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this calculation (1186197.29 - 1260711.19 + 226318.15) three times over now, and I am getting 151804.25.

The `M` at the end of the number just means it's a `Decimal`, by the way.

Comment: I did the calculation with Mathematica, with exact symbolic calculation, and it gives 607217/4 = (607217 * 25)/(4 * 25) = 15180425/100. I think we can be pretty sure the `decimal` result is correct. ;)

Comment: It seems from the poster's comment on MusiGenesis's answer that he/she is merely confused somehow about the arithmetic itself and is trying to check the answer manually.